# 1and1 domain name redirect HTTP or Frame with Heroku host?

Tags: heroku, redirect

So I purchased a domain from 1and1, say it's `www.mysite.com`, and am hosting my app on Heroku `myapp.herokuapp.com`.  I have two options for forwarding the domain - HTTP and Frame.  HTTP forwarding seems to just redirect my URL from `www.mysite.com` to `myapp.herokuapp.com`, which isn't what I want.  But I am having a problem with Frame redirecting - if I navigate on my site to various pages (e.g. `myapp.herokuapp.com/users`), it will still say `www.mysite.com` on the top, but not `www.mysite.com/users`.  How can I get the URL path to display correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't want to use the (i)frame method - it's bad practice and you'll get the issues you're having now.

What you probably want to do is:

1. Attach www.yourdomain.com to your Heroku app (via the web interface or the CLI[1])
2. Set up a CNAME record to point `www` to `yourapp.herokuapp.com` with your DNS provider, or use the Zerigo DNS[2] add-on if you don't have DNS hosting already (sounds like you *do*)
3. (Optional) Set up a re-direct to direct http://yourdomain.com to http://www.yourdomain.com, via your DNS provider/domain registrar - this is optional, but useful as Heroku does not recommend pointing your root domain (yourdomain.com) to their A records in case they change.
4. (Optional) Re-direct http://myapp.herokuapp.com/ to http://www.yourdomain.com/ from within your application code or similar (e.g. config.ru if you're using Rack to serve your content)

[1] https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
[2] https://addons.heroku.com/zerigo_dns

Comment: it was step 2, the cname, that did the trick.  that turned out to be all I had to do.